# I am using symfony2 ! is it possible to use two actions for the same route ?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to use two actions in the same page.html.twig

My methode was : 
First, to define My route in the controller as annotation like that :

```
 /**
 * Test controller.
 *
 * @Route("/NoteByStudent")
 */
```

**And for the action :**

```
/**
     * Lists all Test entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="test")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template("AcmeMyBundle:page.html.twig")
     */
```

**and to call it in my routing.yml file like that :**

```
NoteBy:
resource: "@AcmeMyBundle/Controller/TestController.php"
type : annotation
```

**Seconde, to define the other Controller action like that :**

```
Note_By_Student:
    pattern : /NoteByStudent
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:Test:GetTestByStudent}
```

And when i run, it always take the first route and not both ! Any solution ?

Comment: you can use the same action for different @Method. i.e "GET"/"POST", etc

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 action by route.

There are other method for this.For example, in the first twig action:

```
{% render "AcmeMyBundle:Test:GetTestByStudent2" } %}
```